# I cannot get 2 usually simple javascript functions to work with my PHP files

Tags: javascript, php

I am setting up a simple php form to collect entries and insert/show them to a myphpmyAdmin db, this works fine. The little problem I'm having is when i try to put in a small bit of js to clear text and also give a popup alert, neither will work, can somebody help me please.

Here is my Javascript file:

```
function clear(){
    document.getElementById("in1", "in2", "in3", "in4", "in5",).value= "";
}

function saved() {
    alert("Well done yourself, you have saved an entry to the database.");
}
```

And here is my php file:

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CS230 Assignment 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h3>Diary:</h3>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">

<div id="table">

  <table>

      <tr>
        <th>When/Where</th>
        <th>Event</th>      
        <th>Emotion</th>
        <th>Automatic Thoughts</th>
        <th>Rational Response</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" style="height:500px;" name="in1" id="in1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="height:500px;" name="in2" id="in2"></td>      
        <td><input type="text" style="height:500px;" name="in3" id="in3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="height:500px;" name="in4" id="in4"></td>
        <td><input type="text" style="height:500px;" name="in5" id="in5"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

</div>

<div id="buttons">

    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save Entry" onclick="saved()">

</div>

</form>

    <div id="clearButton">
            <button id="clear" onClick="clear();">clear</button>
    </div>

<form action="show.php" method="post">

    <input type="submit" name="show" id="show" value="Show Diary">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check your console. because there is 1 comma too much in the "clear()" function. And I'd assume your save() function doesnt work because the "submit()" of the formular is priorities over it

Comment: "text" `<input>` elements can be any size you want, but they're not intended for blocks of text like paragraphs. If you want to let people type in sentences and paragraphs, you'd use `<textarea>` elements instead.

Comment: cheers I have the save function working now somehow.

Comment: also yeah i might change them to textarea

Comment: thanks textareas working better now but still cannot get clear function to work

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementById()` function takes **one** argument. If you want to fetch a list of elements, you can use `.querySelectorAll()`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#in1, #in2, #in3, #in4, #in5");
```

That returns a node list, so you'll have to iterate to perform an operation on each one:

```
function clear(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#in1, #in2, #in3, #in4, #in5");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
      elements[i].value = "";
}
```

*edit* — you'll probably want to use a name other than "clear" as "clear" is likely to collide with something; in-line event handlers are highly susceptible to that sort of issue. Alternatively you could explicitly reference `window.clear()`:

```
 <button id="clear" onClick="window.clear();">clear</button>
```

Comment: Thanks that makes good sense, I have tried this but to no avail though.

Comment: @TomL so what happens? Are errors reported in the console?

Comment: No when I click the clear button it just does nothing. I have changed the js as the above comment but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @TomL OK have you *checked* the developer console?

Comment: no I will have a look at it again tomorrow must get busy with other stuff thanks for your help, hopefully I'll spot my error tomorrow

Comment: @TomL I think you may be having a name collision issue - try changing the name of the "clear" function to "clearInputs" or something like that. [Here is a jsfiddle that works.](https://jsfiddle.net/wcrtv0s3/)

Comment: That did the job, yeah must have been an issue with the name, works now, cheers again Pointy.